# Convert an array of string key pairs to an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have this data structure:

```
[
  'ecl:hzl byr:1926 iyr:2010,pid:221225902 cid:61 hgt:186cm eyr:2021 hcl:#7d3b0c',
  'hcl:#efcc98 hgt:178 pid:433543520,eyr:2020 byr:1926,ecl:blu cid:92,iyr:2010',
  'iyr:2018,eyr:2026,byr:1946 ecl:brn,hcl:#b6652a hgt:158cm,pid:822320101'
]
```

I'm looking to convert those array values to objects instead of strings. I understand I need to do a `map` with a `split(' ')`, but unsure of the logic inside of there.

Desired output:

```
[
  {ecl: 'hzl', byr: 1926},
  {hcl: '#efcc98', byr: 1926}
]
```

etc. with all of the fields.

I've tried:

```
.map(values => { let pair = values.split(':'); obj[pair[0]] = pair[1]; return obj })
```

But seem to get the same object repeated over and over, from the first index of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to get each element of the array as a separate object then try this:

```js
const input = [
  'ecl:hzl byr:1926 iyr:2010,pid:221225902 cid:61 hgt:186cm eyr:2021 hcl:#7d3b0c',
  'hcl:#efcc98 hgt:178 pid:433543520,eyr:2020 byr:1926,ecl:blu cid:92,iyr:2010',
  'iyr:2018,eyr:2026,byr:1946 ecl:brn,hcl:#b6652a hgt:158cm,pid:822320101'
]

const output = input.map((string) => {  // for each string in array
  const pairs = string.split(/[\ ,]/);  // split by space or comma
  const object = {};                    // create an object
  for (pair of pairs) {                 // for each pair in string
    const parts = pair.split(":");      // split by colon
    if (parts.length == 2) {            // if you get 2 parts after splitting
      object[parts[0]] = parts[1];      // use the first part as a key and the second as a value
    }
  }
  return object;
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
const arr = [
  'ecl:hzl byr:1926 iyr:2010,pid:221225902 cid:61 hgt:186cm eyr:2021 hcl:#7d3b0c',
  'hcl:#efcc98 hgt:178 pid:433543520,eyr:2020 byr:1926,ecl:blu cid:92,iyr:2010',
  'iyr:2018,eyr:2026,byr:1946 ecl:brn,hcl:#b6652a hgt:158cm,pid:822320101'
];
const res = arr.map(x => Object.fromEntries(x.replace(/,/g, ' ')
   .split(' ').map(y => y.split(':'))));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: The OP needs the byr property to be a number.

Comment: @Ele I'm not sure that is important to them, since the accepted answer does not do that either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
array = array.map(val => {
          var obj = {}
          val.split(' ').forEach(keyValPair => {
            var keyVal = keyValPair.split(':')
            obj[keyVal[0]] = keyVal[1];
          })
          return obj;
        })
```